# R: Using "or" to test for string equality (without grep)

Tags: r

I know this is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

If I have a vector of strings like this:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "bb", "c", "d", "dd", "e")
```

And I want to check which elements are equal to either "b" OR "d" exactly, so not using grep, what should I do?

I was expecting something like:

```
a == "b" || "d"
```

to get this result:

```
[1] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Obviously that command does not work, and I am not sure how to use "or" in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `a %in% c("b", "d")`

Comment: Not sure why I did not think of that, thanks!